# Locust RPS does not match user count

Tags: load-testing, locust

Why does Locust does not report RPS as greater than or equal to the user count? As you can see from the images below, despite have 100 users, RPS never reach close to 100.

[image]

[image]

Furthermore, there seems to be dips in the graph when running with high user count (1 million)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can reach RPS equal to use count only if response time will be 1 second sharp.

- if response time will be 500 ms - you will get 200 RPS
- in case if response time will be 2000 ms - you will get 50 RPS

and so on

Check out [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second) for more comprehensive explanation if needed.

If you want to conduct the load of 100 RPS you can take a look at [Locust issue 646](https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/646) and choose the workaround you like the most.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not understand your first point, in the graph the response time is is below 30ms. Why is RPS not above 100 then? It's lesser than that based on your example calculation

Answer (score 1):

In addition to response time Dmitri mentioned, your code will also play a factor in the RPS you'll be able to hit. [`wait_time`](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#wait-time-attribute) in particular can limit RPS by increasing the amount of time between one user finishing their tasks and another one being spawned to replace it.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74294057/7355637) has more details about `wait_time`'s effect on response time but the majority of that will also apply here to you trying to hit an RPS target.

For your second graph, the dips you mentioned and the wild swings in RPS, general downward trend in RPS, and upward trend in response time are most likely mostly due to the system you're testing being unable to consistently handle the load you're throwing at it, with a bit of overloading your workers thrown in for good measure, especially at the higher end of the user count. Depending on your code, Locust may not be able to generate the 250,000 users you're wanting. Looks like it's possible Locust started falling behind after you hit 50,000 users. Each worker may only be able to easily maintain 10,000 users. You may need to make some changes to your code or increase the number of workers you're using to get better performance. See the [Locust FAQ](https://github.com/locustio/locust/wiki/FAQ#increase-my-request-raterps) for more details.